# CSS: How can I set background from point to window's edge?

Tags: html, css, background

I have encountered a small problem with my website. In several places I have to apply this kind of thing:

[image]

And to be more specific - I need this red area to be in this lighter green color. This means that **I have to apply background to element, from certain place, all the way to the edge**. It has to be dynamic (RWD). So this bothers me, because I bet it is really easy to solve.

Code here:

```
<div class="menu container-fluid">
    <nav class="innermenu container relative">
        <ul class="menu-list large standard">
            <li class="home-link-menu-li">
                <h3>
                    <a href="/" title="Strona główna">
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="Strona główna" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/" title="Strona główna" id="headlink9" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>Strona główna</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/pl/i/Informacje-o-firmie/16" title="O nas" id="headlink12" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>O nas</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/pl/n/list" title="Blog" id="headlink11" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>Blog</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/google.pl" title="Galeria" id="headlink13" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>Galeria</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/pl/i/Gwarancja/12" title="Gwarancja" id="headlink7" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>Gwarancja</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="/pl/i/Kontakt/15" title="Kontakt" id="headlink6" class="spanhover mainlevel">
                        <span>Kontakt</span>
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="newsletter-top hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail" class="newsletter-input">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-red">
                        <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
                        <span>Subskrypcja</span>
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And CSS (less file):

```
.menu{
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
background: @getecomGreenDark;

.innermenu{
height: 58px;
line-height: 58px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;

.newsletter-top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;

  form {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;

    input {
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 100px;
      border: 0;
      background: @getecomGreenLight;
      color: #fff;
      max-width: none;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    }

    button {
      height: 100%;
      max-height: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100px;
      max-width: none;
      background: @getecomGrey;
      color: #000;
      border: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 2px 0 0 0;

      .border-radius(0);

      &::after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid #EDEDED;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: -10px;
        top: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm adding another SS of the whole menu bar:
[image]

Comment: So as someone - who already deleted his answer - told me, creating a <div> which supposely should expand to 100% width of area, didn't work. I tried positioning, displaying, width, height, etc - non of those works. Anyone else has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the answer. Pseudoclasses come in handy.

Look what I've changed in the previous code.

```
.menu{
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  height: 58px;

    /* right */
    &::before {
      content: '';
      background: @getecomGreenLight;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* left */
    &::after {
      content: '';
      background: @getecomGreenDark;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    .innermenu{
      height: 58px;
      line-height: 58px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      background: @getecomGreenDark;

  ....
```

Basically we have a `.menu` element in which we have `.innermenu`. So we do as it follows:

1. set background for `.innermenu` - so it will cover the center (in my case)
2. set `::before` for `.menu` - it will work as right side, we give it a background we want, and set it to 50% of width, position absolute, and right to 0 - so it always sticks to right side, and always has 50%
3. same for `::after` - 50% width, position absolute and left = 0

Here is a sketch of this idea:
[image]

I guess thats the best way to solve it.